# Why cannot I see the image file in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-media

I tried to load an image file, but it didn't work. I uploaded the image file by admin. Thanks for the help!

**here is my code**

in `urls.py`

```
path('main/archive/<int:video_id>/', views.loadphoto, name='loadphoto'),
```

in views.py

```
def loadphoto(request, video_id):
     target_img=get_object_or_404(Record, pk=video_id)
     context={'target_img':target_img.picture}
```

in models.py

```
class Record(models.Model):
    record_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    picture=models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.record_text
```

in img.html

```
<img src="target_img">

<a href="{%url 'main'%}">Main</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You Need To Join Your Media directory to your app

Here is the Way You Can Do That:

First You Need To Add This in Your **`Setting.py`**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'your folder directory')

#for example app/media or something
```

Then You Need To Create Media Url Here is The Way:

Then You Need To Add in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('main/archive/<int:video_id>/', views.loadphoto,name='loadphoto'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then You Need To Add This in Your **`Html File`**

```
<img src='{{ target_img.url }}'>
```

You Can See More Details Here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Answer (score -1):

`ImageField` is derived from `FileField`. In order to display the image in your template, you should provide its url, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

The source attribute should instead by populated as follow:

```
<img src="target_img.url">
```